# Failed opening required 'dompdf_config.inc.php'

Tags: php, composer-php, dompdf

I am stuck in a very annoying error when trying to load dompdf lib via composer.

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'dompdf_config.inc.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.15/lib/php')

I can tell my php configuration is sure loaded DOM extension

Here is the test code

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");
$html =
    '<html><body>'.
    '<p>Hello World!</p>'.
    '</body></html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);

$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("hello_world.pdf");
```

I installed dompdf via composer:

What am I missing ?

Comment: have you installed it like it is described in https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf?

Comment: Are you basing your code on the [instructions from the wiki](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/DOMPDF-and-Composer-Quick-start-guide)?

Answer (score 2):

With the way you have placed your `required` statement.

```
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");
```

the file `dompdf_config.inc.php` has to be in the same path as your script.

Comment: I load dompdf via composer

Answer (score 0):

If the default location of your PHP extension(s) and application(s) doesn't match you can set your include path using (for example):

```
define('INCLUDE_PATH', '/home/username/php');
@ini_set("include_path", INCLUDE_PATH);
```

If you don't know the location of your PHP extensions check your PHP configuration or ask your hosting company.

If you don't want to change the value of this option then find out where **"dompdf_config.inc.php"** is located and **use its full path** when doing **require_once**.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that you need to do before having dompdf be in a usable state when using Composer.

I followed the installation instructions when using Composer found in a pull request:

https://github.com/adrianmacneil/dompdf/commit/8435a0c2f889698c9edc92ca461f78b27df45549

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by removing the dompdf added by composer and downloaded a version that contains `autoload.inc.php` and in my code i've added

```
require_once ('vendor/dompdf/dompdf/autoload.inc.php');
```

Then to avoid the `Failed to load PDF document` error,you have to add `ob_end_clean();` like in the code below

```
ob_end_clean();
// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();
```